# Teamcity - shortest job first?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, scheduling

We have a teamcity server and limited number of build agents. Some of the build configs are long running, some others are short.

Is there a way I can configure Teamcity such that it implements [Shortest Job First](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_job_next) or similar algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can manage build queue creating priority classes using [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Ordering+Build+Queue#OrderingBuildQueue-ManagingBuildPriorities). This functionality was built as open source plugin. You can read about this [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Build+Queue+Priorities) and source code is [here](http://svn.jetbrains.org/teamcity/plugins/priority-queue/trunk/). So if current functionality not enough for you, you can try write your own plugin based on existing.

Comment: Thanks, this is better than plain first come first serve. However, its still a bit static. TeamCity does a decent job in learning the time for each build configs (to estimate time remaining), I was expecting something intelligent based on this. But this helps, thanks. Will look at writing something inspired by your reference.